# correct configuration for nginx to localhost?

Tags: configuration, nginx, localhost

I just installed nginx and php fastcgi about an hour ago, and after reading examples of a quick starting configuration, and the nginx documentation etc, I just cant get it to work.

No matter what I change or try, I always only get the "Welcome to Nginx!" screen on "localhost/..." - I cant even call a simple index.html

My config:

(the stuff in the comments is what I tried out)

```
// default nginx stuff (unchanged)

server {
    #listen 80 default_server;
    #listen 80 default;
    listen 80;

    #server_name localhost;
    #server_name _;

    #access_log /var/log/nginx/board.access_log;
    #error_log /var/log/nginx/board.error_log;

    #root /var/www/board;
    #root /var/www/board/public/;
    root /var/www/board/public;

    #index index.html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
}
```

If I understand it right, this should be the easiest setup, right? just define `listen 80;` and  `index index.html;` but I just cant get it to work

The file /var/www/board/public/index.html exists and has content

Before I waste 2 more hours trying out something, can someone of you give it a quick watch and tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Fundamentally you hadn't declare location which is what nginx uses to bind URL with resources.

```
 server {
            listen       80;
            server_name  localhost;

            access_log  logs/localhost.access.log  main;

            location / {
                root /var/www/board/public;
                index index.html index.htm index.php;
            }
       }
```

Comment: Well, I had - I stated that the 'commented' lines where what I tried out - so server_name localhost was already tried - but I'll try again your setup, give me a minute

Comment: Yes, I didnt have `root` and `index` inside of `location / {}` because of http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls

Comment: @Katai I take it your good now? either way you still need a location entry, as for that link its basically saying don't copy/paste, check out http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration#PHP_via_FastCGI for PHP/nginx

Comment: @Katai `This works. Putting root inside of a location block will work and it's perfectly valid. What's wrong is when you start adding location blocks.` basically putting root outside guarantees that any/every location will have a root, so empty location will have a resource to send, but thats if you have many, many locations ...

Comment: Yes it works now. I found the problem - the localhost was overwritten automatically by `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*` - there a `server {}` with localhost was already configured. This killed my own configuration. Thank you very much, wouldnt have found it before!

Comment: @Katai Thanks for mentioning `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*`. That solved my issue too.

Comment: @Katai me as well. By changing the config from 'localhost' to '0.0.0.0', I was able to avoid the conflict.

Comment: can we change the server name (localhost) to any other name when we are working on localhost?

Comment: In my case, the problem was in the file `conf.d`, there a server {} with localhost was already configured

Comment: why example.localhost not work in Nginx in windows server? (It work on browser, I test it )