# How can I make a 'GET' request in the same server that php project deployed?

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

Situation:

I deployed my php project as a web server in the machine A, using nginx and fastcgi, and the config file is as following:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  alpha.kimi.com;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    root /alidata/www/;
    location ~ .*\.(php|php5)?$
    {
            #fastcgi_pass  unix:/tmp/php-cgi.sock;
            fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi.conf;
    }

    location / {
        root   /www/admin/;
        index index.php;
        if (!-f $request_filename){
            rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?$1& last;
        }
    }
    location ~ .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|bmp|swf)$
    {
            expires 30d;
    }
    location ~ .*\.(js|css)?$
    {
            expires 1h;
    }


    access_log  /data/log/nginx/access/output.log;
    error_log   /data/log/nginx/access/error.log;
}
```

so when I make a 'GET' request from my local machine as:

```
curl http://alpha.kimi.com/app/redirect/taskpush?build=10&gcdata=1
```

there will be json returned

```
{"res":200,"msg":"success","extra":[]}
```

However when I made the same request in the machine A, it just hanged there, and returned nothing. I also tried:

```
curl http://localhost/app/redirect/taskpush?build=10&gcdata=1
```

and

```
curl http://localhost:9000/app/redirect/taskpush?build=10&gcdata=1
```

all not working. I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061788/correct-configuration-for-nginx-to-localhost and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634574/how-to-make-nginx-to-listen-to-server-nameport

Comment: How did you go with this in the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure nginx to listen via localhost or 127.0.0.1 for it to work.

See http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen for full instructions.

You can add multiple listen statements eg:

```
listen localhost;
listen 127.0.0.1;
```

Also see this for more detail: https://serverfault.com/questions/655067/is-it-possible-to-make-nginx-listen-to-different-ports